# What is the purpose if the feast of visitation and on what day of the year is it celebrated?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, feasts, liturgical-calendar

Recently read a little mention of feasts the Catholic Church commemorate regarding events in Mary's life. Does the feast of visitation refer to the conception of Jesus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visitation commemorates the event described in [Luke 1:35-56](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201%3A39%E2%80%9356&version=ESV), in which Mary goes in haste to her relative Elizabeth:

> <sup>**39**</sup> In those days Mary arose and went with haste into the hill country, to a town in Judah, <sup>**40**</sup> and she entered the house of Zechariah and greeted Elizabeth. <sup>**41**</sup> And when Elizabeth heard the greeting of Mary, the baby leaped in her womb. And Elizabeth was filled with the Holy Spirit, <sup>**42**</sup> and she exclaimed with a loud cry, “Blessed are you among women, and blessed is the fruit of your womb! <sup>**43**</sup> And why is this granted to me that the mother of my Lord should come to me? <sup>**44**</sup> For behold, when the sound of your greeting came to my ears, the baby in my womb leaped for joy. <sup>**45**</sup> And blessed is she who believed that there would be a fulfillment of what was spoken to her from the Lord” (English Standard Version; the *Magnificat* immediately follows).

In the Catholic Church, it is celebrated on [May 31](http://usccb.org/bible/readings/053116.cfm). It is liturgically a *feast*, hence one notch below (so to speak) a *solemnity*. Since it is not feast of our Lord, it is not celebrated if it falls on a Sunday.